Which tag is appropriate for MultiBit and Electrum clients: "thin-clients" or "lightweight-clients"?
Currently, there are 2 questions using the "thin-client" tag and there is no tag description.
A thin client application is defined in Wikipedia as "simply one which relies on its server to process most or all of its business logic". 
It could be argued that a Bitcoin client does the bulk of the important processing, or on the other hand that most of the processing has already been done (and stored in the blockchain). 
Both Electrum and Multibit describe themselves as lightweight clients rather than thin clients.
For this reason, I personally would prefer to use the "lightweight-client" tag for those clients. However, I'll put it to a vote before I change anything.

The tags should be synonyms of each other anyway, so it doesn't really matter.

The "lightweight-client" tag is better to use for questions relating to Electrum and Multibit.

The "thin-client" tag is better to use for questions relating to Electrum and Multibit.
